# Haskell even number iteration

Tags: haskell, recursion, iteration, fold

I'm trying to drop all odd number from a list of integers.. however having some problems (I'm a total newbie), here's my code:

```
 evenfunc :: [Int] -> [Int]
 evenfunc li =
        x = head li
        y = tail li
        if even x
          then x : myevenfunc xs --take head an pass tail recursively
        else
          drop x li : myevenfunc xs --drop head from list and pass tail recursively
```

Its giving me a 'parse error on input '='' message when trying to run this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean to use the [`let` keyword](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the given solution using `filter` should be preferred, but the recursive version could be instructive, too:

```
evenfunc :: [Int] -> [Int]
evenfunc [] = []
evenfunc (x:xs) = if even x then x : tail else tail where
    tail = evenfunc xs
```

The first line `evenfunc [] = []` takes care of the base case - the empty list. You were missing this in your solution, and if you call `head` on an empty list, you get an exception.

The second line deconstructs the list using a pattern: `x` is the head and `xs` is the tail. Then we use `if` pretty much as in imperative languages, with the difference that it returns a value (so it is in fact closer to the ternary operator `x ? y : z` in Java etc). In order to avoid repetition, we define a sub-expression `tail` in the `where` clause. If it is weird to you to use things before you define them, you can use `let` instead, which works similar. Of course, calculating `tail` means to execute the recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell isn't an imperative language in which you order statements, but you can achieve your method by binding values to identifiers using `let`:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = let y = x + 5 in y * 3
```

But even using this your function has a few problems:

- your recursive call is wrong (use `evenfunc`)
- your usage of `drop` is probably wrong
- you never define `xs` anywhere

All in all, it is probably best to remodel your approach using library functions. `filter` does exactly what you want:

```
evenfunc list = filter even list
```

Or, even:

```
evenfunc = filter even
```

Comment: Thanks - what if I wanted to map over the list and drop elements? how would you structure that?

Comment: @ronaldmurphy That is exactly what `filter` is for.